# ActiveMQ Start dropping messages from Queue after memory limit is exceed

Tags: stack, activemq-classic, fifo

In our project i need to push messages to ActiveMQ and keep them persistant. When i send new message and memory limit is exceed oldest message in queue should be dropped/removed from queue or replaced with new one.

I do not want to clear whole queue, queue works like fail safe message backlog for our product so i need to keep last x amount of messages in the queue.

I have tried to look from google and no luck so far.

Here is my policy settings.xml

```
    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
              <policyEntry queue=">" producerFlowControl="false" memoryLimit="5mb"  > 

                   <messageEvictionStrategy>
                    <oldestMessageEvictionStrategy/>
                   </messageEvictionStrategy>

            <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="100"/>
            </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>

                 </policyEntry>
          </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eviction policy object only apply to Topics, you cannot use them on Queues as the service contract of a Queue is that it stores all messages until they are either consumed or their lifetime expires via a set TTL value.  The broker can store messages on the Queue to disk and thereby remove them from memory but for Topics the contract is looser and the eviction policies allow the messages that are in memory waiting to be dispatched to a Topic consumer to be dropped.

You can only control the lifetime of messages in the Queue via a TTL value.

Answer (score 1):

You can not remove persistent messages from disk until and unless we delete it or consume it. You can enable producerFlowControl to throttle producer so that it will accept new menage after consumption of old message from queue or as Tim suggested set TTL on message.